# RestKit Error "Failed transformation of value at keyPath _ to representation of type 'NSString"

Tags: ios, restkit, foursquare

I am new to iOS and I am trying to map the Foursquare Explore API and I keep getting the below error

```
E restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:440 Failed transformation of value at keyPath 'name' to representation of type 'NSString': Error Domain=org.restkit.RKValueTransformers.ErrorDomain Code=3002 "Failed transformation of value '(
"Jenkinson's Pavilion",
"The Spot Pizza Grill",
"The Ark Pub & Eatery",
"Jenkinson's Inlet Bar",
"Outside the Box Patio Bar",
"The Off Shore"
)' to NSString: none of the 2 value transformers consulted were successful." UserInfo=0x14Righd3b500 {detailedErrors=(
"Error Domain=org.restkit.RKValueTransformers.ErrorDomain Code=3002 \"The given value is not already an instance of 'NSString'\" UserInfo=0x14d26ab0 {NSLocalizedDescription=The given value is not already an instance of 'NSString'} "Error Domain=org.restkit.RKValueTransformers.ErrorDomain Code=3000 \"Expected an `inputValue` of type `NSNull`, but got a `__NSArrayI`.\" UserInfo=0x14d73060 {NSLocalizedDescription=Expected an `inputValue` of type `NSNull`, but got a `__NSArrayI`.}"
```

here is my code:

```
- (void)configureRestKit
{
// initialize AFNetworking HTTPClient
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.foursquare.com"];
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];

// initialize RestKit
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];

// setup object mappings
RKObjectMapping *venueMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Venue class]];
[venueMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"name": @"venueName"}];

// register mappings with the provider using a response descriptor
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor =
[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:venueMapping
                                             method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                        pathPattern:@"/v2/venues/explore"
                                            keyPath:@"response.groups.items.venue"
                                        statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];

[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
}
```

Right now I am just trying to map the 'name', what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your key path of `response.groups.items.venue` drills too deep because `groups` is an array and then `items` is also an array. Drilling to the first array and mapping at that level is fine. But, when you drill to the next array level you are forever trying to convert an array into a single destination object. This is why you see an array of names in the log output.

So, you need to back up and map at a different level, generally using a container object, and potentially moving part of the key path to the mapping instead of the descriptor.